# How do I reduce the code duplicate here? Surely I can do this with reflection or generics?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am working with WPF and MVVM, and so have a lot of properties in my view models that are bound to stuff in the view. The majority of these properties look like this...

```
private DateTime _newRevisionDate = DateTime.Now;

public DateTime NewRevisionDate {
  get {
    return _newRevisionDate;
  }
  set {
    if (_newRevisionDate != value) {
      _newRevisionDate = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(ViewModelUtils.GetPropertyName(() => NewRevisionDate));
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using MvvmLight, which is where the RaisePropertyChanged() method comes from, and have used the ViewModelUtils.GetPropertyName() method to create a string from the property name, avoiding the need for magic strings.

Now, the problem is that if I add a few such properties to a view model, I end up with a large amount of almost identical code. This just cries out for some clever refactoring, so I can just use a single line of code to define each property.

However, I haven't been able to find any way to do this yet. What would be nice is to be able to do something like the standard C# automatic properties...

```
public DateTime NewRevisionDate { get; set; }
```

...but have it call RaisePropertyChanged() whenever the property is set to a new value.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You may consider writing a plugin for Fody similar to [this one](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).

Comment: Hello Joachim, thanks for the reply. Fody looks amazingly powerful, but I don't think I have the time at the moment to learn how to write a plug-in for it. Shame, because it could be just what I want. Maybe one day :)

Answer (score 3):

> This just cries out for some clever refactoring, so I can just use a single line of code to define each property.

Well you can make it a single line now. It's just a very *long* line :)

C# 5 makes this slightly easier with [caller info attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx), so you don't need the `GetPropertyName` part - and that's the ugliest part of your current code.

The other thing you could do would be:

```
set
{
  _newRevisionDate = PossiblyFireEvent(RaisePropertyChanged, _newRevisionDate, value);
}
```

where `PossiblyFireEvent` would take the property name as an optional parameter using the caller info attributes, `RaisePropertyChanged` as a delegate to execute if the two values were unequal, and always return `value`. Not sure it's worth it though.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the reply. Sadly, as this app has to run on WinXP, we can't use C#5, so the caller info attributes approach won't work, although it looks fantastic. I hadn't spotted this one amongst the new features. As for the other suggestion, it doesn't really shorten the code much. What I meant by doing it one line wasn't the "set" part of the property, it was doing the whole property in one line, the the C# auto properties. The way you suggested, I still end up with a separate bit of code (backing field and a getter and setter) for each property. That's what I'm trying to reduce. Thx

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: That's just not something C# supports. Automatically implemented properties are *only* for trivial properties which are "straight-through".

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought as much. It just seems wrong to have so much almost identical code here. I was really hoping I could do something to reduce it